# Homogeneous and inhomogenous system of equations is or is not a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How to show that a solution set of homogeneous system of linear equations $A\overline{x}=\overline{0}$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with n being unknown number of elements of $\overline{x}$? (Excuse any notational inconsistencies)

Similarly,

How to show that a solution set of inhomogeneous system of linear equations $A\overline{x}=\overline{b}$
with $b≠0$ is a NOT a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with n being unknown number of elements of $\overline{x}$?

The definition of vector subspace in my textbook defines this in terms of the usual multiplication and addition operations. Does this mean that vectors of the form $\overline{x}=[x_1,\dots,x_n]^\top$
defined with the multiplication and addition operations, with the given constraint as above, is the subspace?

Answer (score 1):

For the solution set of a homogeneous system, note that $\vec{0}$ is an element of the solution set. Also, note that the solution set consists of vectors with real number entries. As for how to show the solution set is closed under linear combinations, I am unsure.

For the solution set of an inhomogeneous system such that $b \neq 0$, note that $\vec{0}$ will not be an element of the solution set. All subspaces must contain $\vec{0}$, so the solution set is not a subspace.